# list.add("stuff"); crashes

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm trying to make a simple list.

I've got this:

```
    String valuesArray[] = {"473", "592", "1774", "341", "355", "473", "950", "500", "44", "946.35", "750", "950"};
    List<String> valueList = Arrays.asList(valuesArray);
```

Whenever I try to add something to the list, it force closes.

```
    valueList.add("Test");
```

And it really seems to only happen when I try to add to the list. I'm able to get values from the list, just not add to it.

Comment: Age, wrap the calls to the valueList with a try/catch block and print the exception. Nice and simple way to get started on debugging your code.  (Answers below re immutable collection are of course correct.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see from the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) for `Arrays.asList()`, the `List` returned from that method is fixed size. If you want something more versatile, you might try:

```
List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(valuesArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()` returns a [fixed size list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29). You cannot add to it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to loop through the array and add them in one at a time, then, it won't be a fixed size for the list and you can do all the list operations that you want.